# Correct syntax of put command in ftp?

Tags: batch-file, upload, ftp, command, put

I am having some confusion regarding the `put` command ,

Basically my ftp file is in other folder for example it is in `c:\Test` and the file which I wanna upload is in other folder for example say `C:\Test1`. So is it possible to do it without moving the ftp file to `C:\Test1`.

However I am not able to get how can it be done via put command? Is there any other way or solution for it?

Comment: Add the folder to put command `put C:\test1\filename` should work

Comment: What do you mean by "ftp file" and "file which I want to upload" ?  How are these different?

Comment: Thanks Jens but that does not seems to work for me , I have arleady tried it  . Any other method?

Comment: Toby I meant by ftp file that the main .dat file which will upload other one to the server , Sorry I am only 12 so I dont think I could explain nicely

Comment: Isn't there a `lcd`command with `ftp` (change local working directory)?

Comment: Thanksss a lot Stephan!!! :-) I am 100% sure this will help

Comment: `put C:\test1\filename` definitely works. If it does not, you are doing something very wrong, show us. The `lcd` will work too.

Comment: put file://C:\test1\filename